# How does this React code translate to class representation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand how the code below, which is from Redux examples [TODOMVC](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js), can be written using the class notation. 
The code is

```
const App = ({todos, actions}) => (
  <div>
    <Header addTodo={actions.addTodo} />
    <MainSection todos={todos} actions={actions} />
  </div>
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work, I get `Warning: App(...): When calling super() in`App`, make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed.`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor({todos, actions}) {
      super({todos, actions});
      this.todos = todos;
      this.actions = actions;
  }

  render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <Header addTodo={this.actions.addTodo} />
          <MainSection todos={this.todos} actions={this.actions} />
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is passed to `App` is `props`. And `({ todos, actions })` is just destructuring from `props`. This should work:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { todos, actions } = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
        <Header addTodo={actions.addTodo} />
        <MainSection todos={todos} actions={actions} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

By setting `this.todo = todos` in constructor, you're setting an instance level property. Which means if the props changes later, `Header` and `MainSection` will not be updated.

Comment: The constructor is superfluous now

Comment: ok, now using const { todos, actions } = this.props; and super({ todos, actions }) it works as I expected. But I get the warning, while I think I'm passing exactly what I receive. I understand however  the constructor is superfluous

Comment: @cdarwin, `super({ blah })` means, create a new object with `blah` in it and then pass it to super. Hence the warning. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do what React asks, pass the whole props to the superclass and get out the properties you want explicitly

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.todos = props.todos;
    this.actions = props.actions;
  }

  render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>Actions: {this.actions}</h1>
          {/*<Header addTodo={this.actions.addTodo} />
          <MainSection todos={this.todos} actions={this.actions} />*/}
        </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App todos={[]} actions={'some action'} />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```